# Why are the alphabetical numbering of Appendices missing and the 'appendix' package giving error?

Tags: ieeetran, appendix

I want to alphabetically arrange my appendices like Appendix A, Appendix B, and so on. When I use the appendix package, an error appears 'appendices already defined'. So, with the use of the command \appendix, only the heading 'APPENDIX' is added without any alphabetic order between multiple 'APPENDIX'. The MWE is attached. If anyone could modify it for the desired output. Thanks.

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\makeatletter
\def\endthebibliography{%
    \def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty 'thebibliography' environment}
    }%
    \endlist}
\makeatother 
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}

\begin{document}
    This is body of the document
    \appendix
    This is appendix a
    \appendix
    This is appendix b
    \appendix 
    This is appendix c
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some comments and observations:

- The `appendix` package is *not* compatible with the `IEEEtran` document class.
- The `IEEEtran` class redefines `\appendix` to output an unnumbered section-level header line, "Appendix", centered on a line by itself. The `\appendix` command takes an optional argument, which is placed right below the "Appendix" line.
- The `\appendix` command is further defined by `IEEEtran` to output nothing at all if further `\section` and `\section*` commands are encountered.
- If you simply must impose some formal structure on the appendix material, use `\subsection` rather than `\section` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}
    \section{This is a section header}

    \subsection{This is a subsection header}
    \lipsum[1][1-5]

    \subsection{This is another subsection header}
    \lipsum[1][6-10]
    
    \appendix[Here comes the appendix material] % with optional argument
    
    \subsection{This is Appendix A}
    \lipsum[1][1-4]

    \subsection{This is Appendix B}
    \lipsum[1][5-8] 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved my desired output with the following code. Posting for the purpose that someone may find it useful. Note that an error occurs yet the code produces output.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}
    This is body of the document
    \begin{appendices}
    \section{}
    This is appendix a
    \section{}
    This is appendix b
    \section{}
    This is appendix c
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]